# Есть сервис (или плагин) для удобного форматирования html

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublime-text, notepad++

Есть код **HTML**. Он очень плохо выглядит. То табуляция есть, то её нет. То **CSS** код отформатирован хорошо, либо он в одной длинной строке (здесь даже код **CSS** в самом файле). С **JS** вроде получше, но всё-же есть длинные строки. А самим отформатировать не могу. Во-первых, это долго, во-вторых, я не знаю некоторых нюансов при форматировании (они есть).

Есть сервис (или плагин для Notepad++ или SublimeText) для автоматического форматирования кода? Я искал, есть некоторые, но они все не форматируют код в тегах `<style>`, хоть и написано, что форматируют.

Comment: форматирование имеется в виду в браузере или в коде?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в коде

Comment: Можно открыть файл через инструменты разработчика в Хроме, закладка Sources > Filesystem. В нижнем левом углу кнопка `{}` Format, которая приведет любой код в порядок, в т.ч. минифицированный. (Настройки табуляции под иконкой шестеренки справа вверху: Preferences > Sources > Default indentation)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Спасибо, как раз

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю это то, что вы ищите: https://www.fesevur.com/indentbyfold/

Comment: Я уже пробовал. Форматирования практически нету, и мне нужен перенос длинных строк (вроде был хороший плагин для Notepad++, но я забыл)